# Image url, separate click events for a, img

Tags: javascript, jquery

If i have this html

```
<a>
<img style="display: block; width: 15px;" src="icon-07.png" alt="facebook" width="21" border="0">
</a>
```

is it possible to create click events for img with out trigger click on "a" and vice versa?

I need to do two separate handlers, if the user clicks on image provide an interface to change the image, and a click on "a" should provide an interface to change the URL.

clicks on img are taking precedence when i use

```
$(*div*).on("mouseup",'a', function(e)){}
$(*div*).on("mouseup",'img', function(e)){}
```

Really looking forward to your expert advice.

Regards

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you have to pass the event as **argument** and use `stopPropagation` function.

```
$('div').on("mouseup",'img', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

This behaviour is called `bubbling`. When an event happens on an element, it first runs the handlers on it, then on its parent, then all the way up on other ancestors.

Comment: My bad, i should have thought about this. Thank you :)

Comment: Quick question, when i use "click" instead of mouseup the event bubbles to the "a" as well, is there some explanation to this?

Comment: @Veeru, have a look here : https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the click event from bubbling up, you can use `stopPropagation`:

```
$(*div*).on("mouseup",'img', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  // do your stuff here
})
```

Not sure what do you mean by *vice-versa*. You have only one element under `a`. So, user will have to click on the `img`, and not on the `a` alone.